# Send array to JSON PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I got these arrays

```html
$address = array("1JzSZFs2DQke2B3S4pBxaNaMzzVZaG4Cqh", "12Cf6nCcRtKERh9cQm3Z29c9MWvQuFSxvT", "1dice6YgEVBf88erBFra9BHf6ZMoyvG88")

$amount= array("100000000","150000000","200000000")
```

and I want to convert them to json format like below:

```html
{
    "1JzSZFs2DQke2B3S4pBxaNaMzzVZaG4Cqh": 100000000,
    "12Cf6nCcRtKERh9cQm3Z29c9MWvQuFSxvT": 1500000000,
    "1dice6YgEVBf88erBFra9BHf6ZMoyvG88": 200000000
}
```

I tried too much but couldn't figure out how to do that in PHP, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php):

```
echo json_encode(array_combine($address, array_map('intval', $amount)));
```

Comment: it creats json like this:
{"1JzSZFs2DQke2B3S4pBxaNaMzzVZaG4Cqh":"100000000","12Cf6nCcRtKERh9cQm3Z29c9MWvQuFSxvT":"150000000","1dice6YgEVBf88erBFra9BHf6ZMoyvG88":"200000000"} but i dont want "" around amount

Comment: it works but there is a problem, if some i have duplicate element in $address, this code does not creat json for all of them, but just for one.

Comment: Can you explain what should happen in that case?

Comment: address=array("1cw3eokrgom4jg904jwgero","1cw3eokrgom4jg904jwgero","1cw3eokrgom4jg904jwgero","1cw3eokrgom4jg904jwgero","1cw3eokrgom4jg904jwgero","1cw3eokrgom4jg904jwgero","1cw3eokrgom4jg904jwgero") ;

$amount=array("0.01","0.01","0.05","0.01","1","0.1","0.1")

result will be: {"1cw3eokrgom4jg904jwgero":0}

Comment: Work for me http://3v4l.org/dkvWV, can you help me to better understand what should happen?

Comment: does not work; output in your link is the same as my pc :D
{"1cw3eokrgom4jg904jwgero":0}, 
i want result to look like this:
{"1cw3eokrgom4jg904jwgero":0.01,"1cw3eokrgom4jg904jwgero":0.01,"1cw3eokrgom4jg904jwgero":0.05,"1cw3eokrgom4jg904jwgero":0.01,"1cw3eokrgom4jg904jwgero":1,"1cw3eokrgom4jg904jwgero":0.1,"1cw3eokrgom4jg904jwgero":0.1}

Comment: you can't have the same keys multiple times in an array